# how to draw multiple png images in same page using php

Tags: php

can anybody help me how to draw a multiple png images in a same page using image functions in php...where I can able to create a single image but not more than that....

Comment: Just use two `<img>` tags and two PHP scripts to create the images. -- Maybe your question can be answered more specifically, if you show your actual code and explain what the difficulty is.

Comment: Yes ya I got the output by method of using two image tags also...Your method also working....Thanks for ur help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `<img>` tag to link to the PHP script that generates your image

```
<img src="my_image_drawing_script.php?image_to_draw=1" />
<img src="my_image_drawing_script.php?image_to_draw=2" />
<img src="my_image_drawing_script.php?image_to_draw=3" />
```

and so on

In the PHP script itself:

```
switch (intval ($_GET ['image_to_draw']))
{
    case 1:
        // Logic for drawing image 1 goes here
    break;
    case 2:
        // Logic for drawing image 2 goes here
    break;
    case 3:
        // Logic for drawing image 3 goes here
    break;
    default:
        // invalid input
    break;
}
```

Or, you could have a PHP script for each image if you prefer.

```
<img src="my_image_drawing_script_1.php" />
<img src="my_image_drawing_script_2.php" />
<img src="my_image_drawing_script_3.php" />
```

Comment: hi GordonM,I got the output by the code you given(using of switch statement)...Many Thanks for your help....